# can't retrieve the data from sqlite db

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i have created a method to retrieve all favorites from database, but its not getting any data.

i have added a Log.e to check the count of data, and its come as below:

```
I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database FoodDB.db
fav: []: : is count
```

so please advice me where is the mistake exactly, and how i could call the method from the activity to get all data.

**getAllFavorites method**

```
public List<Favorites> getAllFavorites (String foodId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String[] sqlSelect = {"FoodId", "Name", "Image", "Description", "Components",
                "MenuId", "UserName"};
        String sqlTable = "Favorites";

        qb.setTables(sqlTable);

        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, "FoodId=?", new String[]{foodId}, null, null, null);

        final List<Favorites> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                result.add(new Favorites(
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FoodId")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Image")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Description")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Components")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("MenuId")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("UserName"))
                ));
            } while (c.moveToNext());

        }
        db.close();
        return result;
    }
```

**activity_favorites.JAVA**

```
public class FavoritesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    FavoritesAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorites);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_favorites);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager myLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        myLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        myLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager);

        loadFavorites();
    }

    private void loadFavorites() {




        adapter = new FavoritesAdapter(this, new Database(this).getAllFavorites("FoodId"));


        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "check is it working?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("fav: "+new Database(this).getAllFavorites("FoodId"), ": is count");

    }

}
```

Comment: try changing `Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, "FoodId=?", new String[]{foodId}, null, null, null);` to `Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);` and follow this with `Log.d("CURSORCNT","Rows in Cursor = " + String.valueOf(c.getCount()));`. Run and check the log. If 0 then empty table. If not 0 then it is likely that the filter on **id** results in no rows.

Comment: @MikeT, thank you very much, its working now to get data. but now i'm facing another issue that its bring now the FoodId only, so how could I get the remaining data

Comment: Add 2 more Log lines `Log.d("FOODID","FoodId passed = " + String.valueOf(foodId));` after the cursor count log line added previously. And `Log.d("FOODID","Extracted FoodId = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("FoodId")));` before the line result.add(new Favorites('. Run using the previous lines. What is the passed id? It likely doesn't match any of the extracted Foodid's. If so where/how are you getting the FoodId that is passed (edit your question to include the code that passed the FoodId)?

Comment: @MikeT i have added the 2 more Logs and the result for FoodId passed = nothing.
and the Extracted FoodId = got the correct data from db even when i changed the raw name. but the page have only the Food Id without any other data from DB.

Comment: @Amor writing an answer for a get around, should be finished shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the debugging confirms that you have data in the database and that you can access it and that it appears that you are following the correct steps for utilising a RecyclerView, then in all likelihood the issues are with the FavoritesAdapter.

As a quick way of showing this the following steps and code should show a list but using an ArrayAdapter along with a ListView and a stock layout.

1. Add a ListView to your `layout.activity_favorites.xml`, giving it an id of **listview** (make sure that it will be visible).
2. add 4 lines as class variables (i.e. after `FavoritesAdapter`) :-

   ListView mListView;
   List mFavoritesList;
   ArrayAdapter mAdapter;
   Database mDBHlpr;
3. add  the following lines to set mListView according to the id of the listview added at 1 (after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorites);`) :-

   ```
   mListView = this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
   mDBHlpr = new Database(this);
   mFavoritesList = mDBHlpr.getAllFavorites("doesn't matter as not used as yet");
   mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mFavoritesList);
   mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   ```

   - Note this assumes that the getAllFavorites uses `Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);`

4 Run the App and hopefully you'll get something along the lines of :-

[image]

- Note mjt.usingrecyclerviews.Favorites is the package/class name. i.e. it's listing the rows BUT because the default of the ArrayAdapter is to use the toString method and none is defined in the Favorites class it uses the default. So package class and then the identifier for the  respective object.
- This screen print was after running the code/App twice each adding 3 rows to the Favoorites table, hence the 6 rows in the ListView.

Adding the following method to the Favorites class :-

```
public String toString() {
    return "Id=" + String.valueOf(this.foodid) + " Name=" + this.name + " etc.....";
}
```

results in :-

[image]

- So now, a 3rd run and there are 3 sets of the same 3 people (as expected)

#### What to do next.

As previously said the issue is very likely with your adapter. As such I'd suggest marking this as answered, (i.e. you can now retrieve data from the database or least least know that it's there) and then ask another question, this time providing code for the adapter.

Comment: thanks so much for your help and support, its showing exactly as you said. i will check my adapter again.

Answer (score 0):

download "sqlite expert personal" and copy your db file to "sqlite expert personal". You can view your table and values inside and also write down the same query that you are writing in your app and be sure if its working properly or not.